# htaccess isn't working correctly with Kohana 3.1.x

Tags: .htaccess, kohana-3

I need to be able to access everything under /admin_dir without the Kohana framework interfering, since the admin_dir doesn't use the framework at all.

First off, here's my .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

#Allow the admin page to be accessed
RewriteRule ^/?admin_dir(.*) admin_dir$1 [L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

This is the .htaccess file that comes with Kohana, minus the addition of the admin_dir rule.  However, no matter what I do I can't access the admin_dir. I get a Kohana exception saying that it couldn't find a route to match if I try to access /admin_dir/index.php, or that the URL couldn't be found if I try to access /admin_dir.

The ONLY way I seem to be able to access the admin_dir is by commenting out the very last line of .htaccess.  The admin_dir isn't part of the Kohana framework, so I just want to bypass it all together.  I've found similar posts on SO about this, but nothing that works for my situation.

**Edit:**
I do have an .htaccess file in the admin_dir/ for password protection.  The contents are below:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin Page"
AuthUserFile "/home/mysite/.htpasswds/public_html/beta/admin_dir/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Thanks in advance for your help, this has been a thorn in my side for way too long!

Brian

Answer (score 1):

So apparently having the .htaccess in my admin_dir directory is what was causing my problem.  I don't know why or how, but after making a small change to the root .htaccess file and removing the password protection, it's all working now... with the exception of no password protection. :(  I guess for that I'll just need to write a dumb little authentication thingy for it.

Here's the modification we made to the root .htaccess file:

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin_dir.* [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Thank you all for your help!

Brian

Comment: Well .. try this then (if you still want password protection -- it will not take long and it worth checking it): put your .htaccess back into /admin_dir (the one you have removed). Add these lines: `RewriteEngine On`  `RewriteOptions inherit`. May work...

Comment: @LazyOne - Tried it just now, didn't work.  I still get the same Kohana exception error. :(
I *really* appreciate your tenacious help on all this!

Answer (score 0):

Does commenting

RewriteRule ^/?admin_dir(.*) admin_dir$1 [L]

solve your problem when you try to access http://domain.com/admin_dir/index.php ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I get the following Kohana exception: `HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: admin_dir/index.php`.  But admin_dir/index.php exists, so I'm not sure why `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is not failing...

Answer (score 0):

The rule below will tell Apache to not to do any URL rewriting for URLs that start with `admin_dir`

```
RewriteRule ^admin_dir.* - [L]
```

If it still does not work (it does work fine here on my test box), try removing leading `^` -- it is less accurate (as it will also be triggered for `some_admin_dir`) but as long as `admin_dir` is a unique across whole website (no other URLs have that text) then it should be fine.

---

**UPDATE:**
You may try putting this into your .htaccess from `/admin_dir` -- worth trying it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin_dir/

# stop rewriting if file/folder exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: @LazyOne : I've tried that too and it isn't working either.  It's almost like apache is broken or something.  Is there something else I should look at?

Comment: @Donde Where did you put it -- replaced what you have tried yourself (after `<Files .*>`) .. or ? It works here when I do my local testing. Try putting in on very top, just after `RewriteEngine On`. BTW -- what is the real folder name (I mean -- maybe it has some special chars that require additional escaping .. or is it very simple as `admin_dir`)? If still nothing -- then there must be some setting/configuration option that prevents this .htaccess file from been used by Apache (I assume that mod_rewrite IS enabled).

Comment: @LazyOne - mod_rewrite is definitely enabled.  There's no special chars, that is the dir name. I moved it to the top and I still get the same problem of it redirecting to the index.php file

Comment: @Donde Do you have any other .htaccess files in subfolders that may affect this (in `admin_dir` for example)? Can you check if you have any Rewrite rules in Apache config (if you have access)? Please enable URL Rewriting debugging (if you can) and see the logs. Otherwise I see no other ways how can I help you from overhere (I cannot figure out what else it may be) :(

Comment: @LazyOne - I've edited my post and put the contents above.  There is an .htaccess file in the admin_dir but it's just for PW protection...

Comment: @Donde That .htaccess seems absolutely fine to me. I can only suggest enabling URL Rerite debug: `RewriteLog "\path\to\rewrite.log" RewriteLogLevel 9`. The rule I gave you works absolutely fine here. You could try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin_dir [NC]  RewriteRule .* - [L]` instead, but that pretty much the same. Also see my update in answer.